# sql query count daily difference / count new rows, no date column

Tags: mysql

I have a database for our local real estate listings, there are no dates or timestamp columns.

I would like to be able to get out just the rows that were added in the past day or two.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this data out?

EDIT:
Each new row does get a new id number which is incrementally higher, so I can ORDER the results by newest.

Would it be possible to save my query count in a file, or in another database, each day, then calculate the difference and use that as my number of new listings?

Comment: Good luck with that.

Comment: There's no direct way of doing that without `DATE` columns. However, a long (and bad) way of getting what you want (assuming listings added last day) is to create a job taking backup of concerned tables every day and the next day compare your table against backup to get the listing added yesterday! Too much work, but I don't see any other way out.

Comment: @Incognitio Also requires precognition, I suspect.

Comment: @Strawberry why don't you refrain from posting comments unless it is conducive to a solution...

Comment: @mys I'm always hesistant to say that something is impossible, because someone always comes along immediately after and proves that it can be done, but I think this task is, near enough, impossible - at least for historical data. Of course what you do moving forwards from today is an entirely different matter.

Answer (score 0):

"Would it be possible to save my query count in a file, or in another database, each day, then calculate the difference and use that as my number of new listings?"

I understand that you can't change the table structure to add a date...so instead, I suggest to have a cron job at midnight that will create a record with a date and the higher ID at this moment. This way, you will be able to finde a range of ID for a specific date...

If you relayed on query count, you will get problem when you will start to delete some rows...